# Java Sprint endpoint matcher using ** not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on an example project to understand better endpoint matchers::

```
@GetMapping(path ="/v3**", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> genericV3GetRequestProxy(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy);
```

But when I send this http call it is not matching:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/v3asdasd/asd
```

Instead if I send this one it works:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/v3asdasd
```

In the end the correct solution is just:

```
@GetMapping(path ="/v3/**", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

But I wanted to understand why it behaves like I showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you added a slash to your URI you created a separate path segment, as `/` is defined as the path separator per RFC 3986.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3